# python opencv detect differences between images of products with surface defects

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on a surface defects detection problem.
I have a plastic material which might have different type of defects: scratches, small breaks, spots of a color very similar to the object, black spots.
The problem is that I can't train an ML model because there are too few products with defects.

I've thought about writing a code that looks for the differences between ok and ko product but I can't detect all the differences correctly. For example I can't find the light spots. Maybe I am wrong in my approach. Can you tell me which is the best way to detect these defects?

Here are two codes I tried. For both the codes I use the good image and the image with defects. Before using them i warp them to get the same size and position.
I am attaching also two sample images.

CODE1

```
before = cv2.imread('img1.jpg')
after = cv2.imread('img2.jpg')

# Convert images to grayscale
before_gray = cv2.cvtColor(before, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
after_gray = cv2.cvtColor(after, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Compute SSIM between two images
(score, diff) = compare_ssim(before_gray, after_gray, full=True)
print("Image similarity", score)

# The diff image contains the actual image differences between the two images
# and is represented as a floating point data type in the range [0,1] 
# so we must convert the array to 8-bit unsigned integers in the range
# [0,255] before we can use it with OpenCV
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")

# Threshold the difference image, followed by finding contours to
# obtain the regions of the two input images that differ
thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

mask = np.zeros(before.shape, dtype='uint8')
filled_after = after.copy()

for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 40:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(before, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(after, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], 0, (0,255,0), -1)
        cv2.drawContours(filled_after, [c], 0, (0,255,0), -1)
```

CODE 2

```
difference = cv2.subtract(img1, img_2)
plt.imshow(difference)
plt.show()

# color the mask red
Conv_hsv_Gray = cv2.cvtColor(difference, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(Conv_hsv_Gray)
plt.show()

# RGB_img1 = cv2.cvtColor(Conv_hsv_Gray,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# plt.imshow(RGB_img1)
# plt.show()


ret, mask = cv2.threshold(Conv_hsv_Gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV |cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
print(ret)
print(mask)
plt.imshow(mask)
plt.show()
RGB_img1 = cv2.cvtColor(mask,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(RGB_img1)
plt.show()


print(difference)
difference[mask != 255] = [0, 0, 255]
print(difference)
# add the red mask to the images to make the differences obvious
img1[mask != 255] = [0, 0, 255]
#img2[mask != 255] = [0, 0, 255]
```

[image: black spot and breaks]

[image: white spots]

[image: ok]

Answer (score 0):

a possible approach would be to train a model on your OK product, then on detection set a threshold to the detection percentage

Comment: 'm sorry I don't have any code at hand to show you

but you can simply sum the deviation of each pixel, then normalize the result, but this mehthod will be sensitive to the difference of the environment (lighting, offset of the object to the catch, ...)

A second method is to go through the deep learning (example with tensorflow) and learn via several product OK a generalized model, then use this model learned in your script the result is likely to be already normalized. this method is more complex but more effective.

Comment: Ok. I am really interesed in the second method. I have worked before with deep learning and tensorflow, however I haven't understand very well what do you mean with training a model only on OK product... Do you have any website / video I can look at? Thanks

Comment: [hub](https://tfhub.dev/s?module-type=image-object-detection)  [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub) [keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint)  [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/training)

Comment: there is a gold mine of information on the github of tensorflow, and on the tensorflow hub, I put you some link above

Comment: the goal is to take a model ready to be re-trained. once the model is re-trained it is enough to use it for example for detection and process the score of the result,

Comment: an example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) for image classification

Comment: an other link [retraining](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_image_retraining.ipynb)